Delayed program running of c program when i declare a pointer
Below is a program related to linked list, specifically a insertion operation.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void insertAtFirst(Node **head_ref, int data) {
    struct Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    // if (*head_ref == NULL) {
    //     *tail_ref = newNode;
    // }
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *head_ref; 
    *head_ref = newNode;
}

void printList(Node *node_pointer)
{
    while (node_pointer != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node_pointer->data);
        node_pointer = node_pointer->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = NULL;

    int no_of_elements;
    printf("Enter number of elements to be entered: ");
    scanf("%d", &no_of_elements);
    for (int i = 1; i <= no_of_elements; i++) {
        int data;
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &data);
        insertAtFirst(&head, data);
    }
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}

It works fine until i declare a second Node pointer "tail" in the main() method. When i declare the "tail" pointer the program takes some time to start running, about 2-3 seconds, it doesn't effect the compilation time though. Before it was much faster. How can declaration of a pointer make such a delay?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void insertAtFirst(Node **head_ref, int data) {
    struct Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    // if (*head_ref == NULL) {
    //     *tail_ref = newNode;
    // }
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *head_ref; 
    *head_ref = newNode;
}

void printList(Node *node_pointer)
{
    while (node_pointer != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node_pointer->data);
        node_pointer = node_pointer->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;

    int no_of_elements;
    printf("Enter number of elements to be entered: ");
    scanf("%d", &no_of_elements);
    for (int i = 1; i <= no_of_elements; i++) {
        int data;
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &data);
        insertAtFirst(&head, data);
    }
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}

Also if I transfer the for loop from the main() method to insertAtFirst() method the same problem occurs. Don't know why

What is the input you are providing?

for the data of the linked list node, of int type

No, we mean, give us the exact, complete, literal data that is being passed on standard input.

just some random number like 3, but the problem is not there, the prompt "Enter number of elements to be entered:" takes some time to be displayed after that the programs runs just fine.

Does the problem continue on subsequent runs of the program?  On some OSes, notably MacOS, the first run of a program after it is recompiled takes several extra seconds to start up, due to code signing I believe.  This has nothing to do with what changes were actually made to the program.  If you run the program a second time without recompiling again, you won't see the delay.

Not on subsequent runs. i see this problem after the first run after compilation

but if that's the case, why i don't see the problem when i don't declare the "tail" pointer?
